# How to print html inside a div using laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question, I want to print information from my database that is coming in a variable to the view. My concern is that the information stored in the database has html tags and I can't print the text without the tags in the div. I have tried to apply it with inverse quotes but doesn't seem to work.

[Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIlqU.png)    [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrQXq.png)    [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nSIw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `echo strip_tags($variable);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the data without laravel removing the tags automatically try using `{!! $variable !!}` instead of `{{$variable}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can print the variable passed to the view like this:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

But beware, this makes your users vulnerable to XSS attacks. Check the docs for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data